# Is it possible to make the upper layer recognize a kind of gesture while passing other kinds to lower layer?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, layer, touches

I am working on an iPad application where the user can place several editable text boxes on a canvas. Each text box should be able to be moved by dragging it around with one finger. The user can rotate the selected text box using two fingers.

I would like to have two layers. The upper layer would receive rotation gestures with two fingers. However, if the user touch the screen using only one finger, it should pass the touch event to a text box (custom UIView) on the lower layer. Is it possible to do this?

My first attempt is to count the number of touches from `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and `-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` using `[touches count]`. If the number of touches is two, it performs the rotation. If it is a single touch, it would "loop" through all the text boxes and check if the touch is inside which text box, and perform the moving for that box.

Is there a better way to do this? Is looping going to be a problem when there are a lot of text boxes?

By the way, I'm new to stack overflow. Please tell me if my question is too vague or anything and I'll try to explain it more clearly.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` for rotation and a `UIPanGestureRecognizer with maxNumberOfTouches = 1` for dragging.

UIGesturesRecognizers are easier to handle then simple touch API : gesture recognition is mostly a state-machine problem (where is the touch, where was it before, is it still valid, what kind of gesture characteristics I have so far). Handling several gesture through the methods `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` , etc..., might soon turn as hell of states!

Comment: Thanks for answering.
The problem is that when i set the upper layer to recognize rotation gestures, all boxes on the lower layer are blocked and cannot receive any touch event. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: I want the user to be able to rotate a selected text box by performing rotation gesture anywhere on the canvas.

Comment: When I use gesturesRecognizer, I set them on my VC main View (in your case your 'canvas'), and I see wich item (text box) it is targeting when state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` then I just have to call this item appropriate method. I don't have several recognizers (one / item),I only have one recognizer / gesture type. Then you can manage GesturesRecognizers interactions through `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`